# How to measure the state of charge of a battery in arduino

Tags: voltage-level, battery

This questions has been formulated several times with not clear answer, and I wonder if there is one.

it is well stablished from several sources that measuring the voltage of a battery alone is not good indicator of the State of Charge (SOC) of the battery because voltage does not decline proportional to the soc.

Another solution (http://fritzing.org/projects/battery-charge-level/) suggest measuring the voltage (with analogread) between two resistors connected to the gnd and vcc of the circuit (I presume this constantly draw power) and then choose what is the critical voltage of the circuit.

However, my question is how to measure the SOC of a battery using units of 0 to 100% in arduino?

Comment: Are you asking about how to make up a circuit with two resistors, or how to convert the analogRead result into a number from 0 to 100%, or something else?

Comment: What type of battery/charger? I'm using a Li-Ion (4.2V to 2.75V). By measuring the voltage I can determine the percentage of power left. I actually make it 0 to 100 from around 3.2V, as I don't want people to drain the battery completely (Li-ion rechargable).

Comment: I noted that the state of charge of a batery in many graphs I found is shown as percentage values from 0 to 100%. My question is how are those percentage calculated for any given battery? My  guess is that if the batery has let's say 2700 mAh, how much of that is left at any given time, but I am not certain.

Comment: The datasheet of the battery gives you a discharge curve. You can e.g. create a lookup table that converts the battery voltage to a percentage of charge remaining based on this graph. As for the voltage divider; choosing large value resistors will make the current lost negligible. Adding a small capacitor could be used to stabilize the voltage if very high resistance values are used. If the battery is connected directly to the AVR chip, you can use the [internal bandgap voltage to measure](https://github.com/jcw/jeelib/blob/master/examples/Ports/bandgap/bandgap.ino) the battery voltage.

Comment: THe answer [**here**](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/181360/determine-soc-of-a-li-ion-battery/181368#181368) and [**here**](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97393/how-to-measure-state-of-charge-of-a-battery-through-algorithm/97404#97404) 
My answer to the 1st question contains links to "Battery University" which tells what can be achieved and what effort is required.

Answer (score 1):

To do it correctly, you need a coulomb counter. Something like [this](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/battery-management/DS2740.html).

Even that is not fully sufficient, as the charge that can be obtained from a battery depends on various factors, such as temperature and ageing.

More recent batteries have somewhat flat discharge curve, when it comes to voltage, till they run flat, then the voltage drops significantly.
Which means that you would need a very accurate voltage meter.

However the starting point is that you must be able to count how much charge is going in and out.